# Can I have all rows using group in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, group-by

This is an example, table like this:

```
ID  NAME       CATEGORY 
1   vue        javascript
2   django     python
3   node       javascript
4   flask      python
```

is it possible to get group results like this ?

```
[
 [{id: 1, name: vue, category: javascript}, {id: 3, name: node, category:javascript}],
 [{id: 2, name: django, category: python}, {id: 4, name: flask, category: python}]
]
```

I've tried use `group by(category)` and `group_concat()`, but result like this:

```
[
{'id': xxx, name: xxx, category: javascript}, {'id': xxx, name: xxx, category: python}
]
```

Every category just return one data, and not group I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks so much like JSON minus the quotes that I have to assume that's what you were going for. Enter the [JSON1](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html) extension:

```
WITH groups AS
 (SELECT json_group_array(json_object('id', id, 'name', name, 'category', category)) AS grp
  FROM example
  GROUP BY category)
SELECT json_group_array(grp) FROM groups;
```

which returns (after pretty-printing)

```
[
  [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "vue",
      "category": "javascript"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "node",
      "category": "javascript"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "django",
      "category": "python"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "flask",
      "category": "python"
    }
  ]
]
```

If you don't want the double quotes, stripping them out is trivial to do in whatever is using the results.

Comment: Im using flutter sqflite, the result is alreadly a  list, every element in list is a dict, so, its no need json extension. i just want to know how to group the result and return all data(when i use group_concat, just return one data)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want this:

```
select 
  group_concat('{id: ' || id || ', name: ' || name || ', category: ' || category || '}') col
from tablename  
group by category
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u9ze1zJHMo7BGh6Mt434ih/0).
Results:

```
| col                                                                                |
| ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| {id: 1, name: vue, category: javascript},{id: 3, name: node, category: javascript} |
| {id: 2, name: django, category: python},{id: 4, name: flask, category: python}     |
```